# How do I access a python list from a django templatetag?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, yaml

I have created a templatetag that loads a yaml document into a python list.  In my template I have `{% get_content_set %}`, this dumps the raw list data.  What I want to be able to do is something like

```
{% for items in get_content_list %} 
       <h2>{{items.title}}</h2> 
{% endfor %}`
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use a template tag here?  If the view can create the right context for the tag then it can create a context with the list as a variable for normal processing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since writing complex templatetags is not an easy task (well documented though) i would take {% with %} tag source and adapt it for my needs, so it looks like

```
{% get_content_list as content %
{% for items in content %} 
       <h2>{{items.title}}</h2> 
{% endfor %}`
```

Answer (score 3):

If the list is in a python variable X, then add it to the template context `context['X'] = X` and then you can do

```
{% for items in X %}
       {{ items.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

A template tag is designed to render output, so won't provide an iterable list for you to use.  But you don't need that as the normal context + for loop are fine.